# Date not storing after iteration

Tags: android, sqlite, loops, datetime, jodatime

I have an iteration that runs for a set number of times depending on another value which can vary which is why I'm using an iteration that iterates based on that value, inside that iteration I add 30 days to a date once each iteration and then add the results to a table.

**PROBLEMS**

I simply end up with the first instance of adding 30 days which is outside the iteration itself. This means that my values inside the iteration are not being stored properly but I can't see why.

I've checked the DateTime operations and displayed the value of `newdate` and it shows the proper date so it's most likely the storing of the date. But I don't know what's going wrong, it works pre-iteration which is what's got me confused. Why isn't it executing inside the iteration? Does anyone have any idea?

Ex.

```
InitialDate | 3/29/2015
2ndDate     | 4/28/2015<-- This is what's stored which is pre-iteration
3rdDate     | 5/28/2015<-- This is what it's supposed to be after the iteration
so on and so forth....
```

**Values pre-iteration**

```
    //Date stuff
    String startdate = (String.valueOf(Acc._date));
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(startdate);
    DateTime startpoint = new DateTime(dt);
    DateTime whendue = startpoint.plusDays(30);
    DateTime foriteration = whendue;
    String formattedDate = whendue.toString(formatter);

    //Storing initial date
    pay.setDateDue(formattedDate);
    db.AddPayment(pay);
```

**Actual iteration**

```
    while (i < j) {

            //Operation for Date Calculation
            DateTime ndt = foriteration.plusDays(30);
            foriteration = ndt;
            String newdate = ndt.toString(formatter);

            //Adding values to PayTable
            pay.setDateDue(newdate);
            db.AddPayment(pay);

            i++;
    }
```

Comment: I don't see the problem. I have run your code, output is `04-28-2015 01:30:00 |
05-28-2015 01:30:00 |
06-27-2015 01:30:00 |
07-27-2015 01:30:00 |
08-26-2015 01:30:00 |
09-25-2015 01:30:00`

Comment: I set breakpoints as well and ran in debug and got the proper outputs but for some reason the only thing that is inserted per entry is 4/29/2015. 


Which means it's in either `pay.setDateDue(newdate)` or `db.AddPayment(pay)` but both are also used out side the iteration in the exact same way except for being in the iteration and work just fine. Also that in the iteration I have other operations with BigDecimal that are also inserted in the same manner which work perfectly fine.

Comment: Where `pay` instance is created? Do you create it at each iteration?

Comment: No I don't, `pay` instance is created at the start of my `onCreate` and the iteration is at the bottom of my `onCreate`.

Comment: It's not a problem. See Astatine0936's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out what was wrong. Nothing. My roommate played a prank on me and just got back from his trip out of town and explained to me how he changed my `getDateDue` to execute a `plusDays(30)` to mimic my code so that when I called `AddPayment` which calls `getDateDue` it would look like it would work but in actuality would only add 30 days once to the `startdate` no matter what I did.

**Summary**

Roommate is an ass, nothing is wrong with my code. Sorry for this pointless post.